# Contando vocales con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estaba practicando programación y estaba intentando solucionar un problema donde tenia que mostrar las vocales que contenía una frase ingresado por el usuario entonces yo hice este código:

```js
var frase = prompt('escriba una frase y le dire cuantas "vocales" hay en ella');
var numeroVocales = frase.match(/aeiou/g);
alert(`Las vocales de tu farse son: ${numeroVocales}`);
```

y no sabia por que no funcionaba hasta que investigue un poco mas y me di cuentas qu debía de poner le "[]" en el "match" pero no se por que se le deben de poner alguien me podría explicar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como dice la [**documentación**](https://www.javieranto.com/kb/Programaci%C3%B3n/Expresiones%20regulares/#los-corchetes):

> La función de los corchetes en el lenguaje de las expresiones regulares es representar "clases de caracteres", o sea, agrupar caracteres en grupos o clases. Son útiles cuando es necesario buscar uno de un grupo de caracteres.

En pocas palabras, al utilizar los `[]` en la expresión regular, indicamos que la búsqueda serán un conjunto de caracteres, y al no estar usando los `[]`, la expresión regular buscará **una secuencia exacta** de caracteres.

---

Es decir, en el código que proporcionas, si escribimos **aeiou**, nos retornará eso porque la expresión regular **encuentra esa secuencia exacta**:

```js
var frase = prompt('Escriba una frase y le dire cuantas "vocales" hay en ella');
var numeroVocales = frase.match(/aeiou/g);
alert(`Las vocales de tu frase son: ${numeroVocales}`);
```

Y al poner los `[]`, buscamos el conjunto de caracteres encontrados en la cadena, es por eso que te retornará **todas las vocales encontradas en la cadena**:

```js
var frase = prompt('Escriba una frase y le dire cuantas "vocales" hay en ella');
var numeroVocales = frase.match(/[aeiou]/g);
alert(`Las vocales de tu frase son: ${numeroVocales}`);
```

Comment: Gracias me ayudaste a solucionar mi duda ahora

Answer (score 0):

```js
var frase = prompt('escriba una frase y le dire cuantas "vocales" hay en ella');
var numeroVocales = 0;

for( let i = 0; i < frase.length; i++ ) {
    if( frase.valueOf( i ).match( /[aeiou]/g )) {
        numeroVocales = numeroVocales + 1;
    }
}

alert(`Las vocales de tu frase son: ${numeroVocales}`);
```

Dentro del for, mediante la función **valueOf( i )**, vamos tomando el valor de cada letra, y luego la cotejamos con el regex, cuando hay coincidencia, aumentamos en "1" el valor de **numeroVocales**.
Para hacer este código realmente útil, abría que pasar la cadena a minúsculas y quitarle los acentos.